# "How to fix 'Button not moving anywhere after css edit' in HTML & CSS"

Tags: html, css

I have tried watching videos and trying to see how to move it. Its an Add to cart Button with PayPal. Is this a restriction by PayPal or can't I move these buttons because of some issue?

Watched videos, looked at different websites.

```css
.farcrybuybutton {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 165px;
  right: 750px;
}
```

```html
<div class="farcrybuybutton">
  <form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="5SRCENDNXF7QS">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="FarCry Add to Card Button" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: button seems to have been moved in the snippet (as you have right 750px, it has moved off the screen to the left) can you elaborate on what you expect to happen and what is actually happening please

Comment: I expect the button to move to the exact location as I have set but nothing seems to happen its stuck on the left side on the top.

Comment: Then you need to edit your question with a [mcve] demonstrating your problem - as you can see if you run the code you have provided, the button clearly moves

Comment: Sounds like your styles aren't being applied then but as you aren't able to replicate your error in your question there is not a lot we can do to debug it

Comment: ok, this must be the issue with Google Chrome I see. Because it's working on Opera but not with Chrome so I assume there is issues with the browser.

Comment: I use chrome and the code above works just fine

Comment: I am using an outdated version of chrome. Its the portable version